# Transformar HTACCESS em Web.Config

Tags: htaccess

Gostaria de pedir ajuda para exportar esse ***HTACCESS (linux)*** para ***Web.Config* (Windows)**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admincp/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2&request=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Sempre erro em algo, e estou passando raiva já, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: O que é que já experimentou? Era mais fácil se mostrasse o que tem e que erro está a acontecer.

Comment: Já tive a solução, mesmo assim muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom vou postar a solução caso ajude más alguém, meu método foi este.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rule 1m">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\/]+)/?$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page={R:1}&amp;subpage={R:2}&amp;request={R:3}"  appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 2m">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page={R:1}&amp;subpage={R:2}"  appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="rule 3m">
                    <match url="^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?page={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Deis já agradeço a quem pelo menos leu a pergunta!